# In json Parsing how to set the image set

Tags: java, android, json

In this json i have two image path

```
String imgUrl="http://eonion.in/vimalsagarji/static/eventimage/abc.jpg"
```

and second 
`String imgPhoto="Jellyfish82238.jpg"` so I want the first String in this **abc.jpg** replcae with **Jellyfish82238.jpg** and parse in `JSON` so please help me.

Comment: use replace() method of String class

Answer (score 1):

We assume that the URL is dynamic in every time. We assume also that the base URL to get images is

```
http://eonion.in/vimalsagarji/static/eventimage/
```

In this case, we could play with split to perform what you want

```
String imgUrl="http://eonion.in/vimalsagarji/static/eventimage/abc.jpg"
String[] parts = string.split("/");
```

So, then we have :

```
String part1 = parts[0]; // http://eonion.in
String part2 = parts[1]; // vimalsagarji
String part3 = parts[2]; // static
String part4 = parts[3]; // eventimage
String part5 = parts[4]; // abc.jpg
```

Then, we replace part5 by imgPhoto.

```
kString newImageUrl = part1 + "/" part2 + "/" part3 + "/" + part4 + "/" + imgPhoto
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `replace()`

```
String imgUrl="http://eonion.in/vimalsagarji/static/eventimage/abc.jpg";  
String imgPhoto="Jellyfish82238.jpg";
String url= imgUrl.replace("abc.jpg", imgPhoto);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `replace()`. Since `replace()`  will produce a new String, you should assign the new String to imgUrl

```
imgUrl= imgUrl.replace("abc.jpg", imgPhoto);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 String imgUrl="http://eonion.in/vimalsagarji/static/eventimage/abc.jpg";
 String imgPhoto="Jellyfish82238.jpg";
   imgUrl=imgUrl.substring(0,imgUrl.lastIndexOf("/")+1)+imgPhoto;
   Log.d("imagevalueclicked",imgUrl);
```